# How to configure ruby on rails with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have strugle in connection between J2me and ruby on rails under Webrick server...
dats why i need configure with apache..i saw some tutorials about configuring..but it's not working..

Comment: Can you post some links to the tutorials you've tried and also what happens when you say it's not working?

Comment: Have you tried [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Phusion Passenger: http://www.modrails.com/

Also, for performance improvement, do install REE: http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you coming from? Unix, Mac, Windows? Let's assume you're using some Unix variant, as you should, and Apache2 is already properly installed:

1 - install phusion passenger:
 $ gem install passenger

2 - install passenger-apache2-module:
 $ passenger-install-apache2-module

Be sure to read what the passenger-install-apache2-module command output is telling you, in the end it will give you some lines you have to put in some apache configuration files, if you miss that, it won't work. At all.

3 - Edit your vhosts.conf file (under /etc/apache2/) to define a hostname for your application, point to your application's public folder, etc.
[VirtualHost examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html)

4 - Profit.

Commands listed under 1. and 2. might need admin privileges, it all depends on how your environment is set.

WebRick is not for production environments at all, in fact, it's not really good for development either, if you intend on doing some slightly more complex stuff with your rails applications. Other than that, you didn't really give enough detail about your problem, so I hope this answer at least points you in the right direction.